# how can i get to the main file directory on android 10 and 11

Tags: java, android, file-management

I have a problem like this and I could not find a solution. my problem is Now, besides the files I created in my application, I also need to access the files in the main directory. The code I use for this is as follows. When I press the back button it goes to the previous folder.
here is my code

```
 public void DosyaGeri(View view) {

    String yol = ((TextView) findViewById(
            R.id.txtKmlDosyaKonumu)).getText().toString();
    String android = "/storage/emulated/0/";
    String atlama="/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.LiderBilgisayarYazilim.cepmap/files/";




  //  boolean defolt= yol == "/storage/emulated/0/";

    if (File.separator.compareTo(yol) == File.separator.compareTo(android)) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Harita.class));
        return;
    }
    else if(File.separator.compareTo(yol) == File.separator.compareTo(atlama)){
        yol = android;
        DosyaListesiOlustur(yol);
    }
    else {
        yol = yol.substring(0,
                yol.substring(0, yol.length() - 2).lastIndexOf("/")) +
                File.separator;
        DosyaListesiOlustur(yol);

    }
}
```

but this code does not work on xiaomi devices with android 10 or higher. The reason is that it uses a different directory instead of "storage / emulated / 0 /". and it gives access permission error to this directory. how can i solve this.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() on most devices will return "/storage/emulated/0". Use this function to get the external storage path. Please tell what it is on Xiaomi. If your code cannot handle the path then it is not Xiaomi but Android 10 which causes that. Did you try other devices with Android 10?

Comment: `String atlama=..."`. Also here do not hard code that path but use getExternalFilesDir(null);

Comment: It works on other android 10 and above devices.Let me use the directory you told me and try it that way.

Comment: my wish; access the main directory and access the downloads folder from there.